# Can I mix declarative and imperative navigation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have an app with a lot of pages. I was using the imperative navigation system (push and pop) until recently, but I wanted to switch to the imperative system for simpler deeplinking. There's only a few complex areas of the app, and I want to use the RouterDelegate for those and the push/pop for the more straight forward areas. I'm worried though that mixing these will have unintended consequences. Are there any limitations in this approach? Will declaring a stack of pages and then pushing/popping conflict?